# How do we deal with the remaining open game-rec questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, game-recommendations, closing

We currently lack the "shopping recommendation" close reason proposed by badp in what is now the accepted site policy for dealing with game-recs. In light of this, should we leave the game-rec questions that are still open as such until we get this close reason, or should we close them for a different reason? If the latter, what close reason should we use, and should we leave a comment recommending the game-rec area51 proposal?

Comment: Maybe someone should edit the game-rec tag wiki. I don't have enough rep for this...  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-rec/info

Comment: I don't have the badge that's required to edit that tag wiki since I don't ask game-rec questions...what a conundrum.

Comment: I have made an attempt to update the game-rec tag wiki. Let me know if the changes are acceptable and/or if you think something else should be added as well.

Answer (score 9):

We close them as **off-topic**, the same thing we do for actual shopping recommendations, because that's what they are now. We either point them to the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), which states that game recommendations are off-limits, or we point them to a policy post here on Meta. Which probably means someone needs to write up a proper policy post.

And no, the "essay" that badp linked in his suggestion doesn't count.

Comment: +1 for policy post. I'm hoping for something that is softly-worded enough to keep users from feeling discouraged.

Comment: Should this proper policy post be a collaborative effort between the community and the mods, something that the mods lay down, or something that a user proposes and we the community + mods examine in close detail to scrutinize until it fits?

Comment: Isn't S&A a better reason for game-rec questions? (just asking)

Comment: @Juan No. Most rec aren't actually argumentative, and almost any repository of games by criteria can be built purely objectively. The voting is probably going to be subjective, but the question itself can be 100% objective. So S&A is a misnomer that's just going to cause more uproar as people whine that "This isn't subjective".

Comment: ok, fair enough, off topic it is.

Comment: Closed as off-topic is the mother of all close reasons as it covers any question that we don't want to see on the site. The rest are only used for closing questions that aren't really a question or a discussion